Floor beams separating. How to fix?
The main beam supporting the first floor has started to separate along the full length. In most places it's 1/8th inch, but maybe a bit more in the worst spot.
I've read elsewhere that some 3x3 steel plates and 1/2in bolts along the length would pull it back together. Some construction adhesive in gaps would prevent more separation in the future. This is also what a contractor recommended, but I'm worried I should seek out a structural engineer. Would that be warranted or just a waste of money?
House is only 20 years old and otherwise in excellent condition. No other issues seen in the joists, support posts, or foundation.




The steel plates and bolts will be more than enough.  I would not even worry about minor warping like that, maybe keep an eye on it over the years.

Ignore above comment and visit professional catalogue that makes specialized products for that https://www.strongtie.com/resources/literature/wood-construction-connectors-catalog

@Traveler, please explain why you are qualified to determine that crip659's comment is  to be discounted.

...Because if they keep changing their user name we're supposed to forget all the other low-quality comments they have left under all their previous user-names, and consider them an "expert", apparently? One that seems to be spamming for Simpson in that particular comment... Yawn. The name changes, the quality of the content does not.
